# SmartGWT : ListGrid Dragging customizing

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I need to put an HTML code on dragging event. Like there is some HTML text that gets dragged with Cursor.

By default first column of ListGrid goes with Cursor. But I want to generate separate Text for it.

So, is it possible to do that?
Or Is there any other option to do that?

Please help me in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats displayed (by default) during a drag event in ListGrid is defined by [ListGrid.dragTrackerMode](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#setDragTrackerMode%28com.smartgwt.client.types.DragTrackerMode%29) and [**ListGrid.titleField**](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#getTitleField%28%29).

ListGrid will default to first field to obtain the description to be shown during a drag, based on titleField.
If you already have another field in the grid from which you can obtain the text, use `listGrid.setTitleField("other-field-name");`

A custom title can be defined by overriding [ListGrid.getDragTrackerTitle](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#getDragTrackerTitle%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGridRecord,%20int%29)

If multiple records are selected, and dragged, drag tracker/title/etc. will be based on first selected record.

Check other ListGrid methods that allow drag tracker customizations as well.